# SlimPHP + AngularJS PUT route not working

Tags: angularjs, rest, slim

I am getting an error trying to use $http.put. The route is instead hitting my $app->get block in slimPHP.

Here is my controller.js code, where credit is an object:

```
$http.put('/api/credit_module/credits/'+credit.id, credit).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config){
        if(data['errors'].length == 0){
            console.log(data['results']);
        }else{
            alert(data['errors']);
        }
    });
```

And in the slimPHP code, here is the get route for a single credit:

```
$app->get('/credits/:id', function ($id){

include 'DBConnects/credit_module_db.php';
include 'common/response/common_setup.php';

$data = $db->credit("id = ?", $id)->result_array();

if($data){
    $result['status_code'] = 200;                           
}else{
    $result['status_code'] = 101;
}

$result['results'] = $data; 
$result['errors'] = $errors;

echo json_encode($result,128);

});
```

This is the put route, which is not being hit at all:

```
$app->put('/credits/:id', function ($id) use ($app, $v){

include 'DBConnects/credit_module_db.php';

include 'common/response/common_setup.php';
include 'common/response/put_setup.php';

//Error validation is here

if(sizeof($errors) == 0){   
    $row = $row->update($bodyArray);
    if($row != false){
        $result['status_code'] = 200;
    }else{
        $result['status_code'] = 101;
        $errors[] = 'failed to update row';
    }           
}else{
    $result['status_code'] = 101;
}

$result['results'] = $data; 
$result['errors'] = $errors;

echo json_encode($result,128);

});
```

Here is what the request looks like in chrome:
[image: put route]

The results data from the request, however, is coming from the get route rather than the put route, and thus no update is ever occuring.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

It turns out that the server was blocking all PUT and DELETE requests. If you don't have root access and are having weird issues, check with your hosting company.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm whether or not you're hitting the `PUT` route by adding the following quick-and-dirty debug code:

```
$app->put('/credits/:id', function ($id) use ($app, $v) {
    die(var_dump('PUT ROUTE')); // Add this die and var_dump

    // ... snip ...
});
```

Then make a `PUT` request from the command line:

```
curl -v -X PUT http://<your url here>/api/credit_module/credits/999
```

If you get `PUT ROUTE` in the output of the curl request, try the Angular request again to ensure there isn't a problem with the Angular request. If both requests return `PUT ROUTE`, the problem isn't with Slim's routing.

In fact, are you sure the issue isn't in `include 'common/response/put_setup.php';`? Is there a copy-and-paster error in the included code that causes the `PUT` route to return the same as the `GET` route?  That's where I might choose to troubleshoot if the debug proves your `PUT` route is getting hit.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good way to quickly test it out. I did find out eventually that it was actually being blocked by the server itself.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. I'm pretty sure I would have been stumped by that one for quite some time.